# I want to show that $m(({\textbf{x}: 0\leq x_1\leq x_2\leq...\leq x_n\leq 1}))=1/n!$ ,where $\textbf{x}\in R^n$, and m is the lebesgue measure.

Tags: measure-theory

I want to show that $m(({\textbf{x}: 0\leq x_1\leq x_2\leq...\leq x_n\leq 1}))=1/n!$ ,where $\textbf{x}\in R^n$, and m is the lebesgue measure.
 
Futher deduce that $m((\textbf{x}\in R^n :x_j\geq0, \sum x_j\leq1))=1/n!$
 
Let $A=(\textbf{x}: 0\leq x_1\leq x_2\leq...\leq x_n\leq 1)$
My thought is either $m(A)=^{?}m(\prod_{i=1}^{n}[0,1/i])=1/n!$ 
or $m(A)=\int1_Adm=^{?}\int_0^{1/n}\int_0^{1/(n-1)}...\int_0^{1}x_1...x_ndx_1...dx_n=1/n!$
Can anyone give me some hints? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried an iterated integral of $1$ over this region?

Answer (score 2):

This set has the same measure as $\{(x_1,\ldots,x_n):0\le x_{\pi(1)}\le x_{\pi(2)}\le\cdots\le x_{\pi(n)}\le1\}$
for any permutation $\pi$ of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$. Any two of these
$n!$ sets meet in a set of measure zero.

Comment: Thanks，I will try it by your method anyway, but I need to prove it seriously.